# how to split a string by another string?

Tags: c#

I have a string in following format

"TestString 1 **<^>** TestString 2 **<^>** Test String3

Which i want to split by "<^>" string.

Using following statement it gives the output i want

```
"TestString 1 <^> TestString 2 <^> Test String3"
 .Split("<^>".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

But if my string contains "<" , ">" or "^" anywhere in the text then above split statement will consider that as well

Any idea how to split only  for "<^>" string ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By using `ToCharArray` you are saying "split on any of these characters"; to split on the **sequence** `"<^>"` you must use the overload that accepts a `string[]`:

```
string[] parts = yourValue.Split(new string[]{"<^>"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Or in C# 3:

```
string[] parts = yourValue.Split(new[]{"<^>"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: String3? I just started to search for a new unknown class. A typo though, right? :)

Comment: @Benjamin - I misread it as the source variable name (the formatting could be clearer...). Clarified as `yourValue` - better?

Comment: Of course. +1 from me anyway, going with Regex.Split was stupid in the first place..

Answer (score 2):

Edit: As others pointed already out: String.Split has a good overload for your usecase. The answer below is still correct (as in working), but - not the way to go.

---

That's because this string.Split overload takes an array of separator chars. Each of them splits the string.

You want: [Regex.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"<\^>");
string[] substrings = regex.Split("TestString 1 <^> TestString 2 <^>  Test String3");
```

And - a sidenote:

```
"<^>".ToCharArray()
```

is really just a fancy way to say

```
new[]{'<', '^', '>'}
```

Comment: You don't really need a regex here, but you should escape the start-of-string sign: `<\^>`.

Comment: @Kobi: Thanks. I didn't actually expect that and thought I only need to escape ^ in character groups. Tried it and you're obviously correct. Fixed the post.

Comment: Quite the opposite - character groups is the one place you normally don't have to escape characters.

Comment: @Kobi: But ^ is starting a negative character group - so I thought of that usage and somehow assumed that it won't act as anchor in the middle of the text. My bad. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try another overloaded `Split` method:

```
public string[] Split(
    string[] separator,
    StringSplitOptions options
)
```

So in you case it may looks like:

```
var result = 
    yourString.Split(new string[] {"<^>"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Hope, this helps.